# Derive a closed formula for the generating function of this recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

This is a given recurrence relation

$a_n=19(F_0a_{n-1}+F_1a_{n-2}+...+F_{n-1}a_0)$

where $F_n$ is Fibonacci number and $a_0=9$. Find the generating function $A(x)$  of the sequence $a_n$

I get the generating function for $F_n=\frac x{1-x-x^2}$

I try this for hour with derivative method $A'(x)$ but I still do not get it. Can you help me please, any method is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 
$$
  F(x)A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nx^n   \cdot  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Bigl( \sum_{k=0}^n F_k a_{n-k}\Bigr) x^n
$$

we see that $F_0a_{n-1}+F_1a_{n-2}+...+F_{n-1}a_0$ is the coefficient of 
$x^{n-1}$ in $F(x)A(x)\,$, or the coefficient of $x^n$ in $xF(x)A(x)\,$.

Therefore your recurrence relation can be expressed in terms of
the generating functions as
$$
A(x) = 9 + 19 \, x \, A(x) F(x) 
$$
and $F(x)$ is known.

Comment: How did you know the coefficient is $x^{n-1}$?

Comment: @user235116: It follows from the product formula for power series. I have expanded the answer, let me know if that helps. You can also "see" it if you expand the first terms of the product.

Comment: For the first line should it be $F_ka_{n-k-1}$

Comment: @user235116:No, I don't think so.

Comment: Ok, thank you this help alot.